# Static Class Template member initialization

Tags: templates, c++11, visual-c++, static, msvc12

I have an issue when trying to initialize static members of a static class template.

Basically, what I thought this approach would be useful for:
I have a lot of objects, which are of course all of the same Base type but they have differing object types. I just want to manipulate these objects, that's why I decided to use a static template as there are quite a number of different types these object can consist of.

However, for logging and options passing I wanted to add the corresponding members to the template whithout having to write initializers for every derived static class.

Please note that the following code is **not** actually working, because there is some SDK involved.
I'm just aksing for the right approach, not right code.

Thanks in advance. :)

template.h:

```
#ifndef _TEMPLATE_H
#define _TEMPLATE_H

#include "stats.h"

template<class T>
class TemplateObj
{
public:
    static void SetParameters(const Options& options)
    {
        T::_options = options;  // Is this even possible?
        T::Init();
        T::DoStuff(_options);
    }

protected:
    static void Message() { stats.Print("Message from Template static method"); }
    static Stats& TemplateObj<T>::stats = Stats::GetInstance(); // This will not work as this is a non-trivial initializer, how to do it correctly? Stats::GetInstance() retrieves a singleton instance
    static Options& TemplateObj<T>::_options;   // Possible?
};

#endif
```

derived.h:

```
#ifndef _DERIVED_H
#define _DERIVED_H
#include "template.h"

class Derived :TemplateObj < Derived >
{
public:
    static void Init();
    static void DoStuff(Options& options)
};

#endif
```

derived.cpp:

```
#include "derived.h"

void Derived::Init()
{
    // Init stuff here
    TemplateObj::Message(); // Call static method from template directly
}

void Derived::DoStuff(Options& options)
{
    // Do something with options 
    stats.Print("Message from derived static method."); // Access to "stats" here. "stats" should be declared and initialized inside the template.
    options.Load(); // Example
}
```

main.h

```
#include "derived.h"

main()
{
    TemplateObj<Derived>::SetParameters(new Options);
}
```

Comment: Just like with regular non-template classes, you need to declare a static member in-class and then define it out-of-class. [Like this](http://rextester.com/WJKVRK28455)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That's it! I'm quite new to templates so I may have overlooked it. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't need to put `TemplateObj<T>::` before the function definition if it is inside the class definition. The following two are both valid:

```
template<class T>
class A{
    void func( void );
};

template<class T>
void A<T>::func() { /* Okay */ }

template<class T>
class B {
    void func( void ){ /* Okay */ }
};
```

In your case, replace the following `static Stats& TemplateObj<T>::stats = Stats::GetInstance();` with `static Stats& stat() { return Stats::GetInstance(); }`

And the following `static Options& TemplateObj<T>::_options;` with this `static Options& _options;`.

On the other hand, replace this `T::_options = options;` with `TemplateObj<T>::_options = options;`.

Comment: Thanks for this. This not only solves my initial problem but also how to pass other objects. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, as this works for retrieving the singleton, it fails with unresolved external error for the other members. Is it because I miss the out of class defintion?

Comment: @RobertH. Can you post what errors you have right now?

Comment: everything fine now. I just had to add the definitions.

Comment: @RobertH. okay, great! glad to know :)